# What are some licensed (brand) managing software?

Tags: software-recommendation, branding, applications

I went to several interviews for a designer position at a top level company and at the end they told me I couldn't be hired because I didn't know any 'Licensed' brand managing software. Do you know of any 'licensed' brand managing software? 
In my current job we use an online app where we upload all the artwork that we receive from Coca-Cola after we adapt them to our printing standards so they can review it and authorize it.

Answer (score 1):

If you google “Brand Management Software”, you’ll get things like [Resolut](https://resolut.com).

The only thing a designer needs to know about them is how to prepare files for them (file formats, resolutions, profiles, …) and how to upload them.

It’s another one of those pointless things HR demands of creatives, as if it takes longer than five minutes to train and learn. But HR doesn't know anything about designers: Somebody just put it on their list and they won’t wire anybody who doesn’t check all the boxes.

Comment: Hi, not sure how to thank @Wrzlprmft for the edits to my answer, but thank you.